# How to apply mask behavior in primeng calendar (p-calendar)?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am new to angular, in p-calendar I'm not able to apply masking behaviour. Example: If user enters 01012012, I want to change it to 01-01-2012. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng11-calendar-with-mask) is a great example how you can mask a primeng calendar. The example require a little bit of coding and if you have more than one angular project a library could be useful. You create a directive for the p-calendar control from primeng. It's based on the library [inputmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inputmask).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 onKeyDate(event: any){
   event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
  }
```

in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Date:"(keyup)="onKeyDate($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `ngx-mask`. Here you are the documentation: [ngx-mask](https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page)

After installation, you can use it in your input like this:

```html
<input mask="00-00-0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only primeng and combine components like this:
https://stackblitz.com/github/B1ker4nt3nd/CalendarInputMask?file=src/app/mask-calendar/mask-calendar-input/mask-calendar-input.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom library in Angular for MFE with module federations, I created a directive inside my library but it is not possible to export Inputmask. Also, the Inputmask cursor when you use it in MFE doesn't work either

I checked the code of [@ngneat/input-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/input-mask) and the issues of Inputmask, and i updated the code [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1426#issuecomment-770405847) . My directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';
import _Inputmask from 'inputmask';
import type Inputmask from 'inputmask';

const InputmaskConstructor =
  (_Inputmask as unknown as { default?: Inputmask.Static }).default ||
  _Inputmask;

@Directive({
  selector: '[dateMask]',
  providers: [{provide: Inputmask, useValue: new Inputmask()}]
})

export class calendarMaskDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  private el: any;
  private input: any
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private primeCalendar: Calendar) { 
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
   
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    new InputmaskConstructor(this.getDateMask()).mask( this.getHTMLInput() )
    this.input.inputmask.shadowRoot = document.activeElement.shadowRoot
    
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  getHTMLInput(): HTMLInputElement {
    this.input = this.el.querySelector('input')
    return this.input;
  
  }

  getDateMask(): string {
    if(this.primeCalendar.timeOnly) {
      return '99:99';
    } else if(this.primeCalendar.showTime) {
      return '99/99/9999 99:99';
    } else {
      return '99/99/9999';
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't use module federations, you can remove the following line:

```
 this.input.inputmask.shadowRoot = document.activeElement.shadowRoot
```